# API REST to be used for an angular application and a mobile application

Tags: angularjs, rest, symfony

I'm building a REST APIs in Symfony2. The idea is to use these apis from a angular web app and a mobile app. Authentication is required to use the APIs.

I thought in the following possibilites:

- Separate Symfony and angular in diferent projects: 
  The URLs under /api would use OAuth2 to authenticate user (FOSOAuthServerBundle). Both web and mobile app would need to use an access token.
- Include angular inside Symfony: In the web app the users are authenticated using a symfony form, and therefore no need to protect the urls under /api with OAuth2. But how would authenticate users from the mobile app?

Please, any help is good!

In short, what I need is that the APIs can be used from two clients: web app and mobile app

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is always better to choose some solution that is already tested for many people and is used by them. So, I think is better you to use the OAuth technique, so you can consume your api from mobile, web and every other technology.

If you will join the API and WEBApp is up to you. because REST use no session and every call is a new call that you need to check and block or respond. I have an app that has an Codeigniter API and an AngularJS APP in the same project, but thoose does not share any exclusive thing as sessions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently studying and suffering from the same problem and so far the best option I've seen is to keep the projects separate. If you include angularJS in your Symphony project, you will end up using resources that Symphony provides that you won't be able to replicate in the mobile structure. By detaching the server with the client completely, your Web App built only with Angular will be more similar to your mobile app, mimicking the stand-alone application mode.

Personally, I chose JWT Auth since it doesn't require 12 tables in your database, but using OAuth2 would have similar result.

Answer (score 0):

I built e-commerce with FOSRestBundle, HWIOOauthBundle and FOSUserBundle
From server side, generate accesstoken and authenticate via api/login/ api/login_check/
write your security.yml routing access
From client side, call your api. It should render 200 or 403 HTTP_Code.